# Reusing same Puppeteer instance in all Jest tests

Tags: jestjs, functional-testing, puppeteer

### Problem

I'm replacing CasperJS with Jest + Puppeteer. Putting everything in one file works great:

```js
beforeAll(async () => {
  // get `page` and `browser` instances from puppeteer
});

describe('Test A', () => {
   // testing
});

describe('Test B', () => {
   // testing
});

afterAll(async () => {
 // close the browser
});
```

Now, I don't really want to keep everything in one file. It's harder to maintain and harder to run just part of the tests (say, just 'Test A').

### What I've tried

I've looked at Jest docs and read about [setupScript](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#setupfiles-array). It would be perfect, but it runs before every test file. I don't want this because puppeteer setup takes quite a lot of time. I want to reuse same browser instance and pay the setup cost only once no matter how many test files I'll run.

So, I thought about:

```js
// setup puppeteer
await require('testA')(page, browser, config);
await require('testB')(page, browser, config);
// cleanup
```

This solves modularization, reuses same browser instance, but doesn't allow me to run tests separately.

Finally, I stumbled upon possibility to create a custom [testEnviroment](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string). This sounds great but it isn't well documented, so I'm not even sure if env instance is created per test file, or per Jest run. Stable API is also a missing a `setup` method where I could set up puppeteer (I'd have to do that in constructor that can't be async).

### Why I'm asking

Since I'm new to Jest I might be missing something obvious. Before I dig deeper into this I though I'll ask here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE (Feb 2018)**: Jest now have official [Puppeteer guide](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html), featuring reusing one browser instance across all tests :)

It was already answered [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/kdzwinel/status/920745013440647168), but let's post it here for clarity.

Since Jest v22 you can create a [custom test environment](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testenvironment-string) which is async and has `setup()`/`teardown()` hooks:

```js
import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node';

class CustomEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
  async setup() {
    await super.setup();
    await setupPuppeteer();
  }

  async teardown() {
    await teardownPuppeteer();
    await super.teardown();
  }
}
```

And use it in your Jest configuration:

```
{
  "testEnvironment": "path/to/CustomEnvironment.js"
}
```

It's worth to note, that Jest parallelizes tests in sandboxes (separate `vm` contexts) and needs to spawn new test environment for every worker (so usually the number of CPU cores of your machine).

Comment: Thanks! I just gave it a go and it works like a charm. I'm extending NodeEnvironment though as I don't need any browser APIs in my testes.

Comment: Updated the example to reflect your comment, because one usually don't mix E2E test env with unit/integration tests. Thanks!

Comment: We just released stable Jest 22 version, so you can freely use async test environments now, without being beta testers  (updated the post accordingly)

Comment: Great! Thank you :)

Comment: UDPATE: we've added `globalSetup` and `globalTeardown` hooks and compiled this sweet example reusing one browser instance across all tests :). See: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html

Comment: This solves opening a single Chromium instance but what about the page? I would like to have several js files but to test in the same page since I run a SPA. I tried with the same logic as global.__BROWSER__ , like global.__PAGE__ = browser.newPage() but it doesn’t work :(

Comment: @KonradDzwinel / others: if you need node env you can: `testEnvironment: 'node'`