# How can I avoid to start puppeteer for every test?

Tags: jestjs, global-variables, enzyme, create-react-app, puppeteer

I'm currently working with jest and puppeteer. I have multiple tests which use puppeteer. The problem is, that I don't want to start puppeteer each time because this will cause the tests to take way longer then they have to.

I'm using jest inside create-react-app.

I've already tried to:

- use jests puppeteer preset (not compatible with create-react-app)
- define the browser as a global varibale (not possible because it's async)
- build a cache function (just not working because it never caches and always builds the browser new)
- building a custom environment [https://stackoverflow.com/a/46818924/10077966] (not supported by create-react-app)

Comment: Are you running your tests in headless mode? That's a quick and easy way to shave a few seconds off execution times.

Comment: No I'm not. But isn't there a way to start puppeteer only once?

Comment: Did you try the example from the jest site https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer#custom-example-without-jest-puppeteer-preset?

Comment: Yeah ... as soon as I write a async value in global it's undefined + environments not supportes by create-react-app